# Touch joystick interfering with action button

Tags: unity-game-engine, joystick

I'm developing an android app, and I'm using the free touch joystick ([This one](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/joystick-pack-107631?_ga=2.167259194.524403591.1590805424-1298902187.1587437196)) from the asset store. For the most part it works well, but I'm running into an issue. I have it set up so that you use Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") to trigger actions on the scene. However just using the joystick is triggering the fire1 action by default when first pressing on the screen to move the character. I need the joystick to not send a touch input when that happens, is that possible?

This is the code that gets triggered:

```
void Update()
{
    if (canActivate && Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && !DialogManager.instance.dialogBox.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        DialogManager.instance.ShowDialog(lines);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want some help, i suggest you to show your actual code..

Comment: I'll add it in there, but there really isn't much to show.